# Global helper function in ReactTS

Tags: typescript, webpack, react-tsx

In ReactTS 16.9, I have the following the function that returns parameter name only if the generic type TObject has the parameter name as key. If the key does not exist, a compile error will be raised. I always import the object first in my components and then use getPropertyName.

```
const Utils = {
    getPropertyName<TObject>(name: keyof TObject) {
        return name
    }
}

export default Utils
```

Now, I would like to have it **globally**, so that I can use it anywhere in any component, *without* having to import it first.

Do I have to eject my React webpack config? Or is there another way around it?

Comment: Why would you want to have it globally available? What is the problem with importing it?

Comment: For convenience reasons

Comment: It kind of defeats the point of modules. A decent IDE/editor should auto-import it for you. 
You could also add your object/function to the window variable though and extend the Window type. It's a bit hacky though